# How to obtain an SSL certificate from Openshift?

Tags: ssl-certificate, openshift, telegram-bot

I am creating a bot for Telegram, which sends a post request to my node application running on Openshift.

According to Telegram's Bot Faq "You need a valid SSL certificate for webhooks to work" which needs to be passed on when [setting the webhook](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook) for a bot.

According to Openshift they offer "shared SSL certificate[s]" on their free plan. Since I am still experimenting I'd like to avoid switching to a higher plan for a custom certificate.

How can I obtain the SSL certificate as a file, so I can pass it on to Telegram?

Comment: Bronze plan is still free as long as you don't go over the free usage limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to pass the SSL certificate as a file to Telegram (this is for self-signed certificates, like those you might use for local development testing). The `setWebhook` method takes two arguments - `url` and `certificate`. Just pass in the HTTPS url for the `url` argument and omit the `certificate` argument when calling `setWebhook` when using the https://<app-name>-<namespace>.rhcloud.com address.

Comment: Thanks a lot @luciddreamz. I was confused because I got an empty body as a response and the message sent to the bot was nowhere to be found. It seems my mistake was parsing the response.

I found [node-telegram-bot-api](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api) which works like a charm. So I am using that one now.

Your answer made me look for the right solution :)